# Where/how to save global variables?

Tags: tokens

We want to store some global variables for token substitution in civicrm. Think of adding current members of board of managers to letters or other phrases to use in mailings or pdf letters.

Example: token

`{board_members}`

should be substitued by

`Jane Doe<br />
Jim Jones<br />
Bud Foo<br />
Frieda Bar<br />`

Any idea how to store (editable by our staff)? Or should I misuse message templates to store the content? Say I'll create a message template "Board members (don't use as template)". Or an inactive message template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating custom tokens is fairly easy in CiviCRM.

I would create a Group in CiviCRM containing the contacts of all the Board Members. By using a Group, as the Board Members change and are updated in the Group the token will automatically reflect the changes.

Then I would program a custom token that converts `{board_members}` to a list of the names of the contacts in the Group (separated with `<br />`).

The link in @Ramesh's answer should help.

You could probably kludge together a solution using templates or something similar, but it is probably more likely to break and more difficult to upkeep.

Comment: Okay, cool. I thought about relationships to our organization but I think you're approach is quite suitable.

Answer (score 0):

you can create tokens to do the same job - instead of using Global variables

that would be more easier than storing in global variables - I guess

please refer to 
[Custom fields for invoice / PDF](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7567/custom-fields-for-invoice-pdf/7569#7569)

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: Sorry if I did not explain well enough. See edit.